# Autofilter VBA Excel not working for multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns, autofilter

I am currently using an autofilter in VBA and it is no longer working. I have tried a load of fixes and nothing seems to have worked. I am filtering on columns X & Z. This is my current code:

```
    NT.Activate
    AutoFilter = True
    LR = Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    With NT.Range("A1:Z")
   .AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:="Buffalo Bayou"
   .AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="#N/A"
    If NT.Range("J2:J" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
    NT.Range("A2:W" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    BB.Sheets("Worksheet").Activate
    LR1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A" & LR1).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

Comment: `A1:Z` is not a valid range

Comment: Thank you! Must've deleted something!

Comment: What happens when you run your code? How is it different from what you want to happen?

Comment: So my code is not applying the filter so presently i am importing 40000 lines into 20 different files when it should only be a portion of these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    Dim NT As Worksheet, wsPaste As Worksheet
    
    Set NT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NT")
    Set wsPaste = BB.Sheets("Worksheet")
    
    With NT.Range("A1:Z" & NT.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:="Buffalo Bayou"
        .AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="#N/A"
        
        If .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
            
            .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            
            wsPaste.Range("A" & wsPaste.Cells(Rows.Count, "I"). _
                           End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```